# Unable to free up space after pruning unused images from Docker

Tags: windows-10, docker-toolbox

I'm having problem restoring disk space after removing all images from Docker ToolBox. There is `disk.vmdk` virtual machine disk with used space. I see that there is same or similar issue with Docker Desktop.

I tried to use

```
VBoxManage.exe modifymedium
```

with `--compact` flag but with error

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: Compact medium operation for this format is not implemented yet!
```

Any help is appreciated.